# Javadoc is not being generated for Android project

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc

I'm working on an Android project and trying to generate javadoc with the task below, but it doesn't generate anything.

I have tried to trace back the issue to changes in the project. Checking out past commits and trying to create javadoc fails, even though in the past it worked.

The only thing for sure that changed for me that might explain this behaviour is the upgrade to a newer version of macOs Big Sur and updating Android Studio.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Setup:

- macOS Big Sur Version 11.4
- Android Studio 4.2.1
- Gradle 6.5

  ```
    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
            options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        }
        options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
        failOnError = false
        source = variant.javaCompiler.source
        def androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
        doFirst {
            classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(androidJar)
        }
        options {
            links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
            linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after a long time of searching I found the answer: it was the update from AS 4.1.3 to 4.2.x with which Google decided to package Java11 instead of 8.
Building and compiling was possible, but javadoc generation was broken for whatever reason.

Comment: Boy... that's not really a solution, is it?

Comment: Not a solution to the problem no, but it is the answer to my question.